# Trouble with GCDAsyncSocket ReadTimeoutError

Tags: timeout, xmpp

I'm using *XMPP* & *OpenFire* for my iOS project. The internet connection is stable.
Everything is fine on the first sign in. However from the second time on (sign out then sign in again), it rarely works. 
I oftens get **readTimeoutError** after 10-15s :

*Error Domain=GCDAsyncSocketErrorDomain Code=4 "Read operation timed out" UserInfo=0xa8db6a0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Read operation timed out}*

Because of that, the app doesn't jump to **- (void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender**, thus i'm not connected with OpenFire.
I've spent the whole day on this issue but still can't find the solution. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problems you are facing. Please close your sockets correctly, it will be fine.

Comment: can you give more detail where to close socket ...i have same problem occur?